# Label in a button

Tags: android, button

how to add a label in a button, like in the image?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

when click in this button, the label is gone, just to show theres something new in this menu.
I cant think in anything to do that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect questions here to relate to specific programming problems -- but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 1):

You can find some thing which i think it's better called 'Feature Highliter'

This library [TapTargetView](https://github.com/KeepSafe/TapTargetView) is doing this.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create a ImageView programmatically when you need.

```
ImageView financasLabel = new ImageView(context);
```

If you plan to add the view to a RelativeLayout you must use RelayiveLayout.LayoutParams. So you can have to do the same as you know from xml: add layout rules. See the documentation... overall is something like this:

```
RelayiveLayout.LayoutParams params = new 
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

 // TODO set the params
 params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
 ...

financasLabel .setLayoutParams(params);
relativeLayout.addView(financasLabel );
```

To hide the imageView, use:

```
imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE) ;) //Espero ter ajudado marcelo ;)
```